# git svn rebase always rebases master?

Tags: git, git-svn, rebase, git-rebase

I'm trying to create a git repository that has several branches which each track a different svn repository. I want master to be a git-only branch, not one of the svn branches.

Here's my initial setup:

```
$ mkdir repo
$ cd repo
$ git init
$ touch README
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial Commit"
$ git svn init -Rsvn1 --prefix svn1/ svn://...
$ git svn fetch svn1
$ git checkout --track -b svn1 svn1/git-svn
```

So far, so good: git branch -a shows me a local branch named master (which just contains the README file), a local branch named svn1 (which contains my svn repo clone), and a remotes/svn1/git-svn branch. I can create svn2, svn3, etc by repeating the last three commands.

The problem is getting updates: if I run "git svn rebase" while I have svn1 checked out, master gets rebased instead of svn1. This happens even if I use "git svn rebase svn1" or "git svn rebase svn1 svn1".

Is there a way to make git svn rebase leave my master alone?

Comment: I'm not sure you should use --track option for svn clones.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get svn updates w/o rebasing anything use `git svn fetch` command. You can use `git svn fetch --fetch-all` to get svn updates from all defined svn repositories.

If you want to rebase with another branch instead of master switch to another branch first and only then execute `git svn rebase`. This command rebases with current HEAD.

Comment: `git svn fetch` updates my remote branches, but doesn't update my local branches which are tracking the remotes.

I'm running `git svn rebase` while I have my local branch checked out, not while in master. That's the problem I'm asking about.

Comment: Double checked on my host. `git svn rebase` rebases current HEAD and not the master.

Answer (score 0):

You need figure out all the branches that you have. Git needs to track remotes, so list them and find the one you want to rebase against:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
remotes/trunk
$ git svn fetch
$ git rebase remotes/trunk
```